# Access Child controls of split container .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parent-child

I am trying to open a file inside a rich text box that is dynamically created in a tabpage on click. But it is inside a split container along with another element. For some reason when I try to access it, I get a Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Here's the code:

Dynamic creation of said tab page:

```
public class Texttab : TabPage
{
    readonly RichTextBox _text = new RichTextBox();
    ConsoleControl.ConsoleControl ca = new ConsoleControl.ConsoleControl();
    private SplitContainer split = new SplitContainer();

    public Texttab()
    {
        split.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        split.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        split.Name = "split";
        _text.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        _text.Name = "textbox";
        _text.Font = fontx;
        _text.BackColor = Color.FromName(back);
        _text.ForeColor = Color.FromName(front);

        ca.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ca.Name = "cmdbox";
        ca.StartProcess("cmd", null);
        ca.Font = fonty;

        Controls.Add(split);
        split.Panel1.Controls.Add(_text);
        split.Panel2.Controls.Add(ca);


    }



}
```

Code accessing the TEXTBOX and opening the text file:

```
    private void OpenToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            var dx = new OpenFileDialog();
            dx.ShowDialog();
            dx.Filter = Resources.Form1_openToolStripMenuItem_Click_Text_Files___txt____txt_Python_Files___py____py_Javascript_Files___js____js_C_Files___c____c_CPP_Files___cpp____cpp_Shell_Files___sh__bat____sh___bat_All_Files__________;
            RichTextBox selectedRtb = (RichTextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["split"].Controls["textbox"];
            selectedRtb.LoadFile(dx.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
```

Thanks, any help on the issue is appreciated. I am almost positive the issue has something to do with the split control. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to access the RichTextBox like this instead since the Panels in the SplitContainer are not named items.

```
(RichTextBox)((SplitContainer )tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls["split"]).Panel1.Controls["textbox"]
```